# pytest-xdist ssh: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Tags: python, ssh, pytest, pytest-xdist

I'm trying to run remote test (very simple hello world test) execution using pytest-xdist. I'm trying to do it from Windows 10 `cmd` (not admin), the remote machine: Linux Centos 7.9
Tried to run tests locally - no problem.

The remote machine is reachable by ssh (using `mingw`)

This is how I run:

`C:\\Python399\\Scripts\\pytest.exe -d --rsyncdir D:\\my_temp\\remote_test --tx ssh=-FD:\\my_temp\\remote_test\\ssh_config myvmmachine//python=/usr/bin/python3.6//chdir=~/my_py_test pytest_test.py`

D:\my_temp\remote_test\ssh_config:

```
Host myvmmachine
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User mydev
  Port 33556
  LogLevel DEBUG3
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_rsa
```

After run I have following error:

```
D:\my_temp\remote_test>C:\\Python399\\Scripts\\pytest.exe -d --rsyncdir D:\\my_temp\\remote_test --tx ssh=-FD:\\my_temp\\remote_test\\ssh_config myvmmachine//python=/usr/bin/python3.6//chdir=~/my_py_test pytest_test.py
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.9, pytest-8.0.2, pluggy-1.4.0
rootdir: D:\my_temp\remote_test
plugins: anyio-4.3.0, xdist-3.5.0
created: 1/1 workerPseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname python -c "import sys;exec(eval(sys.stdin.readline()))": No such host is known.
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 271, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_sessionstart(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 501, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls.copy(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 119, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 138, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     raise exception.with_traceback(exception.__traceback__)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 121, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     teardown.throw(exception)  # type: ignore[union-attr]
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\_pytest\logging.py", line 775, in pytest_sessionstart
INTERNALERROR>     return (yield)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 102, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\xdist\dsession.py", line 83, in pytest_sessionstart
INTERNALERROR>     nodes = self.nodemanager.setup_nodes(putevent=self.queue.put)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\xdist\workermanage.py", line 68, in setup_nodes
INTERNALERROR>     return [self.setup_node(spec, putevent) for spec in self.specs]
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\xdist\workermanage.py", line 68, in <listcomp>
INTERNALERROR>     return [self.setup_node(spec, putevent) for spec in self.specs]
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\xdist\workermanage.py", line 71, in setup_node
INTERNALERROR>     gw = self.group.makegateway(spec)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\execnet\multi.py", line 133, in makegateway
INTERNALERROR>     gw = gateway_bootstrap.bootstrap(io, spec)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\execnet\gateway_bootstrap.py", line 102, in bootstrap
INTERNALERROR>     bootstrap_exec(io, spec)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\execnet\gateway_bootstrap.py", line 40, in bootstrap_exec
INTERNALERROR>     sendexec(
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\execnet\gateway_bootstrap.py", line 78, in sendexec
INTERNALERROR>     io.write((repr(source) + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\Python399\lib\site-packages\execnet\gateway_base.py", line 483, in write
INTERNALERROR>     self._write(data)
INTERNALERROR> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

On the remote machine `sudo systemctl status sshd -l` shows there was no connection attempt

Could anybody help?